# Send post data from html FORM with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

I am trying to send post data from from with empty action and send the info with javascript to the file that must handle the post information.

Here is my code:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
            <script>    
    function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
        method = method || "post";

        var form = document.createElement("form");

        form._submit_function_ = form.submit;

        form.setAttribute("method", method);
        form.setAttribute("action", path);

        for(var key in params) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form._submit_function_();
    }
    post_to_url("./postinfo.php", { submit: "submit" } );
        </script>   
<form method="post" onsubmit="return post_to_url()">
<input type="text" name="ime">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

So how i can send the post data to `postinfo.php` with javascript with empty action in my html form?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your code you've got 2 calls to `post_to_url` - one that happens after you define the function and one that happens when the form is submitted. I suspect this might be causing problems.

Answer (score 11):

You're quite lucky because there's a JQuery function called "[Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)" which handles this for you!

All you need to do is call JQuery, and use code like this:

```
$('#form_id').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/postinfo.php",
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function() {
         alert('success');
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried but it's not redirecting me to postinfo.php like with action="postinfo.php" in html form. Also it's not giving the success alert. I pasted exactly your code in <script></script> tags before my post form and i added id="form_id" to my form.

Can you please take my code and change it how it will works and show me?

Comment: You haven't got JQuery installed - try adding this line to your <head> tag too: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Furthermore, the point of asynchronous form submission isn't to redirect you; it's to perform a background task. If you wanted a redirect, why don't you just submit the form without any JS?

Comment: I've added this but it's still not working, It's even not giving me Success alert...

Comment: Try replacing your <form method="post" onsubmit="return post_to_url()"> tag with this: <form method="post" id="form_id">

Comment: Got a link I can try? There could be a number of potential issues here :)

Comment: http://www.vemvo.com/test/post.php

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/WWrXF3VE

Comment: I'll make a JSFiddle for you :)

Comment: Okey can't wait to see it. Thank you so much!

Comment: More specifically, I think JSFiddle got denied, so why not try the code I made on your page to see if it's okay?

Comment: Well we know it's not my code because it works in JSFiddle & CodePen -- I just looked at your source and you've put the JS into <script> tags; maybe it's worth defining them like this: <script type="text/javscript"> </script>, and putting that in your <head> tag

Comment: It's still not working can you please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476992/send-html-form-post-data-to-file-with-jquery

Comment: lol okay - I hope it works for you now :) Considering my code actually works, would you be kind enough to upvote & accept answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post";

    var form = document.createElement("form");


   _submit_function_ = form.submit;
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form._submit_function_();
}
post_to_url("./postinfo.php", { submit: "submit" } );
```

change to

```
post_to_url("/postinfo.php", { submit: "submit" } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var ra = document.getElementById("uname").value;
        var rag = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
        $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
        url: "/login",
            contentType: "application/json",
         dataType: 'json',
       data:JSON.stringify({
           username:ra,
           password:rag
       }),
       success: function() {
         alert('success');
       }
    });
        console.log(ra, rag)

    }
</script>
<html>
<form name="myform">
<p>ENTER USER NAME <input id="uname" type="text" name="username"></p>

    <p>ENTER PASSWORD <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd"></p>
<input type="button" value="Check In" name="Submit" onclick= "validate()">


</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<form action="{{ url_for('details') }}" method="post">
<p>ENTER NAME<input id="uname" type="text" name="username"></p>

    <p>ENTER DESIGNATION<input type="text" id="pwd" name="pwd"></p>
    <!--<P>ENTER EMAIL-ID</EMAIL-ID><input id="email" type="text" name="email-id"></P>-->
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">


</form>
</html>`
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 __author__ = 'raghavendra'
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import os
import sys
# os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "your_project.settings")
# sys.path.append(('/path/to/django/project'))
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('temp.html')

@app.route('/save',methods=['GET','POST'])
def details():

    a = request.form.get('username')
    b = request.form.get('pwd')
    print a, b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Is this using a plugin? Is this even JS?