# Send HTML form post data to file with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-post, forms

I am trying to send post data to my post data file handler called `postinfo.php` with jQuery but so far I can make it.

Here is my post.php code:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javscript">
$('#form_id').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://www.vemvo.com/test/postinfo.php",
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function() {
         alert('success');
       }
    });
});
</script>   
<form method="post" id="form_id">
<input type="text" name="ime">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

You can see the page here: http://www.vemvo.com/test/post.php

Here is the code from my postinfo.php:

```
<?PHP

$ime = $_POST['ime'];

echo "Your name is $ime";
?>
```

Here is located postinfo.php - http://www.vemvo.com/test/postinfo.php

So where is my mistake and how I can make it work?
Now it's not sending the data and not giving me the success alert.

Comment: http://www.johnboy.com/scripts/simple-jquery-form-without-page-refresh/contact.php

Comment: Wrap $('#form_id').on('submit', function(e){}) in $(function() { ... })

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery selector isn't going to find that form, since the selector is running before the `form` tag exists in the DOM.  Try wrapping it in the jQuery function to wait for the document to be ready:

```
$(function () {
    $('#form_id').on('submit', function(e){
        // the rest of your code
    });
});
```

It also might be a good idea to `return false` at the end, to further suppress the form's default post action:

```
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "./postinfo.php",
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   success: function() {
     alert('success');
   }
});
return false;
```

Currently the form is posting as normal.  Since the AJAX handler is never attached (because the element doesn't exist when the selector executes), it's just doing a normal document-level form post.  And since there's no `action` attribute specified in the `form` tag, the page is posting to itself by default.  Which just responds with the current page.

**Edit:**  You also have a typo which may be preventing the browser from executing your JavaScript code at all:

```
<script type="text/javscript">
```

You're missing the second "a".  This should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: So what i have to change to make it post the data to ./postinfo.php ?
How my whole code will look like?

Comment: No need to return false!

Comment: @TonnyStruck: As I suggested, you need to wrap your jQuery code in `$(function() { ... });`.  Currently your code is executing *before* the `form` element exists.  (Notice how your JavaScript block is above the `form` element.  It executes inline right away, so it executes before the `form` element is known.)  Wrapping it in the jQuery function will cause it to not execute until the entire document is ready.

Comment: @TonnyStruck: I just noticed you also have a typo here: `<script type="text/javscript">`.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks now it's works well! See the code here (view as source) - http://vemvo.com/test/post.php Are you sure that i need `return false;` and how my whole script will look like. BIG THANKS ONCE MORE!

Comment: @TonnyStruck: I'm not 100% sure that `return false;` is necessary in this case.  You can test it easily enough, though.  It *may* even be browser-specific behavior.  I can't imagine that it hurts anything, so personally I'd leave it in place just in case.

Comment: No need for the return false. All other corrections I made are good practice

Comment: Good to see it working! It was the $(function(){}); that fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

1. You MUST spell `text/javascript` correctly
2. You need to assign the event handler on load
3. There should not be any need to return false as posted by some other people here
4. NEVER call anything submit in a form
5. Wrap your html in body tags
6. Use a correct DOCTYPE
7. For files you can have a look at uploadify or [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Fixed code for point 1 to 6

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Ajax</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    $('#form_id').on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "./postinfo.php",
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function() {
         alert('success');
       }
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head> 
<body>
  <form method="post" id="form_id">
    <input type="text" name="ime">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried your code but it's not giving the success alert. I think it's not sending the data too..

Comment: Please do NOT call anything name=SUBMIT!

Comment: What do you mean ? I have changed my code to look exactly like the one you are giving me and it's not giving the Success alert. Here you can see it - http://vemvo.com/test/post.php

Comment: Very strange. I was sure it was the name="submit" that blocked the event handler. I will look closer

Comment: Typo IN **text/javascript"** was the main reason !

Comment: Can this script send `enctype="multipart/form-data"` type form?

Comment: Hey @mplungjan, this is based on [another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476532/send-post-data-from-html-form-with-javascript/19476594#19476594) that we [wrote a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nBNwU/3/) for. The code the OP is using is from that fiddle. Here's the working fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/nBNwU/3/

Comment: I posted because you'll be able to see a functioning version of the JS - I think the problem is either with the guy's host (security), or something else server-side

Comment: @RichPeck Nothing of the sort The main problem was not spelling text/javascript correctly so none of his JS was executed

Comment: Ok, it's good that it's fixed! I provided the code the OP was using (he was trying to do some weird stuff before using $.ajax), and I also provided the misspelt `text/javascript` code, so I just wanted to point out that the code I actually provided the OP was functional in JSFiddle, and it was his implementation which was likely causing the issue